# I have 2 columns V_DATE AND OTP.... AFTER 24 HOUR OF V_DATE I WANT TO SET OTP COLUMN =0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have 2 columns: `V_DATE` and `OTP`.

I want to set `OTP = 0` when 24 hours have passed after `V_DATE`.

Comment: please provide code that you have tried

Comment: Try schedulers to execute in a timely manner and update the table

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

A sample table contains 3 rows with different date values (split by a few minutes).

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (v_date date,
  3     otp    number,
  4     --
  5     otp_changed_on date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (v_date, otp) values (sysdate + 0 / (24 * 60), 100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (v_date, otp) values (sysdate + 2 / (24 * 60), 200);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (v_date, otp) values (sysdate + 3 / (24 * 60), 300);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

V_DATE                     OTP OTP_CHANGED_ON
------------------- ---------- -------------------
10.05.2018 14:49:27        100
10.05.2018 14:51:27        200
10.05.2018 14:52:27        300
```

The procedure updates OTP; I added the OTP_CHANGED_ON column which shows *when* it happened.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_set_otp as
  2  begin
  3     -- "2 / (24 * 60)" is "1 minute later" (as I'm impatient).
  4     --  You'd use "WHERE SYSDATE >= v_date + 1", i.e. 1 day later
  5    update test set
  6      otp = 0,
  7      otp_changed_on = sysdate
  8      where sysdate >= v_date + 1 / (24 * 60)
  9        and otp <> 0;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Job is scheduled to run every minute (I guess that it is OK, regarding the fact that it is "one day later" you're looking for. It requires you to have the following privileges granted: EXECUTE ON DBMS_SCHEDULER, CREATE JOB.

```
SQL> begin
  2     dbms_scheduler.create_job (
  3        job_name          => 'update_otp',
  4        job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5        job_action        => 'BEGIN p_set_otp; end;',
  6        start_date        => TO_DATE ('10.05.2018 14:30', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'),
  7        repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=MINUTELY',
  8        enabled           => TRUE,
  9        comments          => 'Update OTP to 0');
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The result, several minutes later:

```
SQL> select * From test;

V_DATE                     OTP OTP_CHANGED_ON
------------------- ---------- -------------------
10.05.2018 14:49:27          0 10.05.2018 14:51:00
10.05.2018 14:51:27          0 10.05.2018 14:53:00
10.05.2018 14:52:27        300

SQL>
```

As I said: the only modification you should make is at line 8 in P_SET_PROCEDURE:

```
where sysdate >= v_date + 1
```